# Windows: What could be the reason for a "paging file is too small" error even though there is plenty of physical memory available?

Tags: windows, kubernetes, windows-server-2019, containers, pagefile

In one of our applications, we received an error message indicating *"The paging file is too small for this operation to complete"* while the application was trying to load a DLL (a .NET assembly).

However, system metrics show there was plenty of physical (and virtual) memory available on the virtual machine. Unfortunately, we don't know the page file usage at that point. One specialty of the machine is that the page file is very small (3 GB, not OS-managed) when compared to the total physical memory (32 GB).

Why would we receive a page file error even though there is plenty of physical memory available?

This happened on a Windows VM managed by AKS (Azure Kubernetes Services), so we cannot simply change the page file settings. The application where the error occurred was running within a Kubernetes Pod on that VM.

Comment: `This happened on a Windows VM managed by AKS (Azure Kubernetes Services), so we cannot simply change the page file settings.` does the symptom occur on a  Windows system configured the same, and not in Kubernetes/Azure?

Comment: @GregAskew We cannot really reproduce the situation outside of the Kubernetes cluster, as the whole software system is designed for Kubernetes. I was hoping for general ideas on how that kind of error (paging file too small in the face of lots of physical memory available) could arise on a Windows Server system.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this issue, care to explain why, so I can improve the question?

Comment: `Why would we receive a page file error even though there is plenty of physical memory available?` Windows has a minimum page file size requirement. For a minimal page file, it requires that a small crash dump be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to do a few more experiments in the meantime and it turns out that hitting the container memory limit* also produces the `ERROR_COMMIT_LIMIT` error code (1455), which resolves to the message  *The paging file is too small for this operation to complete*. So, we were just misled by the message; the error was most likely caused by the application hitting its limits and had nothing to do with the paging file after all.

* The container memory limit is a Kubernetes concept which maps to the resource limits enforced by Windows Server Silos and Job Objects, see, e.g., [here](https://thomasvanlaere.com/posts/2021/06/exploring-windows-containers/) and [here](https://blog.quarkslab.com/reversing-windows-container-episode-i-silo.html).

Answer (score 0):

Windows best practice is to set the paging file size to equal to or greater than the total amount of available physical memory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/the-paging-file-size-should-exceed-the-amount-of-physical-ram-in-the-system

On how much did you set it?

Comment: As mentioned above, the paging file is set to about 3 GB (at 32 GB physical RAM). We cannot change this, the VMs are managed by Azure Kubernetes Services. Regarding the optimum paging file size: Thanks for the link! I've also found other recommendations such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/how-to-determine-the-appropriate-page-file-size-for-64-bit-versions-of-windows and . However, as we cannot change it anyway, it's probably moot.